# Cannot deploy custom module that uses the same property name, but under different prefixes

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

System Information

Spring Cloud Data Flow Cloud Foundry: v1.1.0.RELEASE
Pivotal Cloud Foundry: v1.7.12
CF Client (Windows): cf.exe version 6.23.1+a70deb3.2017-01-13
cf-v3-plugin: 0.6.7

I have developed a custom source module that connects to a REST API to get incremental changes to data. The offset information is stored in a database table in a connected Postgres.

I have a module options `@ConfigurationProperties("salesforce")` class that has the properties `username` and `password`. However my datasource properties, `spring.datasource.*` properties also have `username` and `password`. Datasource properties are in the `spring-configuration-metadata-whitelist.properties` file under `configuration-properties.names`.

SCDF seems to rely on the shortened property form, and not use the configuration prefix, which poses a problem for me in this instance as there is no way to distinguish between the properties.

On deployment of the module it fails with the error.

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Ambiguous short form property 'password' could mean any of [spring.datasource.password, salesforce.password]`

Other than prefixing the actual property names with something to distinguish them, is there a way to solve this in a more elegant way.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't ;) (apart from changing the shortname to something else, like `user` and `pwd`, of course)

The short aliasing mechanism is really here to help in the 95% cases where there is no collision. Keep in mind this is Data Flow specific, and your *real* property name is `salesforce.password`